# Cron jobs with Bolt

Tags: cron, bolt-cms

Just a quick question on task scheduling and extending with Bolt CM.

Documentation: https://docs.bolt.cm/v20/tasks

When adding task scheduling to an extension, does the listener have to be specified outside of the class?

```php
use Bolt\CronEvents;

$this->app['dispatcher']->addListener(CronEvents::CRON_INTERVAL, array($this, 'myJobCallbackMethod'));

class MyExtension extends \Bolt\BaseExtension {

    // ...
```

Or does it need to be declared in the initialize function?

```php
use Bolt\CronEvents;

class MyExtension extends \Bolt\BaseExtension {

    public function initialize() {
         $this->app['dispatcher']->addListener(CronEvents::CRON_INTERVAL, array($this, 'myJobCallbackMethod'));
    }

    // ...
```

I assume it's the latter because `$this` outside of the class would be outside of the object context.        
 The documentation makes it look as if it directly follows, so thought I'd double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the `$this->app['dispatcher']->addListener()` call does need to be in a class context.

Oversimplification in the docs there.

Comment: Updated example pushed to the repo here: https://github.com/bolt/bolt-docs/blob/master/source/tasks.md

Answer (score 0):

I got it  in initialize function and it  works  fine

```
 public function initialize()
{
     $this->app['dispatcher']->addListener(CronEvents::CRON_DAILY, array($this, 'run'));

}

public function run(){
 // code to run
}
```